# Fit data to a power distribution (java)

Tags: java, curve-fitting, power-law

Much like in Excel where we can take a distribution and make a trendline for it (power law), how can I calculate that in Java for an array of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`org.apache.commons.math.optimization.fitting`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/optimization/fitting/package-summary.html) includes `CurveFitter` and `PolynomialFitter` that will cover many of the typical excel trend line options. `JFreechart` includes some support for [`Regression`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/Regression.html).

Comment: I am getting values back, but they dont' seem to be at all inline with what i get in excel. I mean, i realize there is some imimentation variance, but orders of magnitude are different.

Comment: I've never compared the two directly. Can you edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that focuses on the fit you're examining?